# Invalid Command AssignUserId when starting Apache on CentOS v7

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

I am very new to Linux. I am following [this article](https://www.vultr.com/docs/securing-a-apache-server-on-centos-6).

Basically, I want to create a VirtualHost for one of my WordPress websites. This server is brand new and it is running CentOS.

I have done `yum install httpd-itk` and the install was fine.

But once I have added `AssignUserId vhost-user vhost-user-group` to the `.conf` file for my website, I get this:

[image: httpd-down]

What I have inside the `.conf` is this:

```
NameVirtualHost nativeleaf.co.uk

<VirtualHost nativeleaf.co.uk>
DocumentRoot /var/www/nativeleaf.co.uk/public
ServerName nativeleaf.co.uk
AssignUserId vhost-user vhost-user-group
</VirtualHost>
```

I can no longer start `httpd`. Why is this happening and how can I fix?

**UPDATE**

I am not sure if I should create a new question for this, but see Andrew's answer. With his help, I have managed to get the modules loaded, and got rid of that error, but now face another error.

[image: bad username]

As you can see, the error says vhost-user is a bad name! As mentioned, I was following a tutorial and that was the user used, am I suppose to change that with something else? The tutorial doesn't mention this.

Comment: Please show us the content of the offending file, /etc/httpd/conf.d/nativeleaf-virtualhost.conf.

Comment: apologies @AndrewSchulman, I've added that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mod_mpm_itk defines the `AssignUserId` directive, I'm guessing you haven't loaded that module in your Apache configuration yet. Be sure the configuration includes the directive

```
LoadModule mpm_itk_module modules/mpm_itk.so
```

As the error message says, "perhaps defined by a module not included in the server configuration." See the docs for [LoadModule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule).

In your `AssignUserId` directive, you should substitute the names of a user and group that are defined on your host, in place of `vhost-user` and `vhost-user-group`. For example, you could create a user `nativeleaf` on your host and add them to the `apache` group:

```
sudo useradd -g apache nativeleaf
```

Then if your directive is

```
AssignUserId nativeleaf apache
```

then web code for the nativeleaf.co.uk site will all run as user `nativeleaf` (in group `apache`), and so be compartmentalized to some extent from the code running as user `apache` in your other vhosts.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSchulman, how do I go about including that module?

Comment: I told you how to do that in my answer. :)

Comment: Hehe, you're forgetting that I'm a total n00b to Linux. Does that line go in a specific file somewhere? Can I put it in [one of these files here](https://www.screencast.com/t/0WG4upW13)? Or create a new file just to house that line?

Comment: I've just noticed that one of those files is called `00-mpm-itk.conf`! I looked inside and [I saw this](https://www.screencast.com/t/RamCBUK01F). I guess I can just uncomment that line!

Comment: Find the place in your Apache configuration where the other LoadModule statements are, and add it to the list. In Centos it might be /etc/httpd/modules.conf. But you can add it to any of the files that are included in the configuration. See /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, which is the top-level file that Includes the rest.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSchulman, the module is now loaded, but getting a new problem :( I wasn't sure if I should create a new question so I've updated this question

Comment: Added to the answer to address that.

Comment: Can I also create a unique group for that new nativeleaf user?

Comment: Yes, with for example `useradd -U nativeleaf`. See `man useradd`.